# ¿Por qué en el momento de compilarlo me sale el error "Constant expression required"?

Tags: c++

Estoy realizando un script en `c++` pero me aparece este error:

> Constant expression required

¿Alguien sabe a qué puede ser debido?

Os dejo mi código:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <conio>

int main () {

       int filas, columnas;
       cout<<"Ingrese el numero de filas"<<endl;
       cin>>filas;
       cout<<"Ingrese el numero de columnas"<<endl;
       cin>>columnas;
       int matriz[filas][columnas];
       for(int i=0;i<filas;i++) {
          for(int j=0;j<columnas;j++) {
             cout<<"Ingrese el valor en la posicion "<<(i+1)<<","<<(j+1)<<" "<<endl;
             cin>>matriz[i][j];
          }
       }
       cout <<"La matriz impresa es: "<<endl;

       for(int a=0;a<filas;a++) {
          for(int b=0;b<columnas;b++) {
            cout<<matriz[a][b];
          }
          cout<<endl;
       }

       getch();
       return 0;

}
```

Comment: ¿En qué línea te marca el error `Constant expression required`?

Comment: Hola Paolo y bienvenido. ¿Podrías añadir más detalles a tu pregunta? No hay ninguna explicación más allá del título. Un saludo.

Comment: C++ es un [lenguaje compilado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenguaje_de_programaci%C3%B3n_compilado) no un [lenguaje interpretado (script)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script) ¿Podrías incluir en tu pregunta **en qué línea** te marca el error `Constant expression required`?

Answer (score 2):

Me he levantado un poco dormido hoy y he mezclado C con C++, espero me disculpéis.

Así a bote pronto y habida cuenta de la poca información que proporcionas (la cual tiende a 0) deduzco que el error te está apareciendo en esta línea:

```
int matriz[filas][columnas];
```

<s>El único motivo para que te de el error en dicha línea es que estás usando un compilador en exceso anticuado ya que el estándar c++03 (que data del 2003) ya admitía crear un array en el stack partiendo de valores variables.</s>

En C, desde el estándar C98 se admiten arrays de longitud variable pero en C++ no. Una cosa es que se toleren y otra que sea una buena práctica. De hecho un array de estas características, en caso de usarlo, no debería nunca abandonar la función en la que ha sido creado.

Ante este problema tienes varias soluciones. Te propongo algunas de ellas:

1. <s>Actualiza el compilador</s>
2. Pasa a usar un array dinámico.

Algo así (por ejemplo):

```
int** matriz = new int*[filas];
for(int i=0; i<filas; i++)
  matriz[i] = new int[columnas];
```

Y por supuesto no hay que descuidar la liberación de la memoria:

```
for(int i=0; i<filas; i++)
  delete[] matriz[i];
delete[] matriz;
```

3. Usar vectores en vez de memoria dinámica.

No es que sea la solución más elegante pero se puede usar igual que un array y no requiere memoria dinámica:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> matriz;
matriz.resize(filas);
for(auto& fila, matriz)
  fila.resize(columnas);

matriz[1][0] = 5;
```

4. Usar un array de una dimensión y simular las dos dimensiones:

La gran ventaja de este mecanismo es que únicamente tenemos una reserva de memoria. Nos ahorramos el bucle de reservas. Otra gran ventaja es que nos podemos aprovechar de la localidad de los datos para evitar paginaciones en la caché:

```
int* array = new int[filas * columnas];

std::cout << array[fila * columnas + columna]; //std::cout << array[3][4];

delete[] array;
```

Como su uso puede ser un poco más complejo lo suyo es encapsular el puntero en una clase:

```
// std::fill
#include <algorithm> 

class Array
{
  int* array;
  int filas;
  int columnas;

public:

  Array(int filas, int columnas)
    : array(new int[filas*columnas]),
      filas(filas),
      columnas(columnas)
  {
    // inicializamos los valores del array a 0.
    std::fill(array,&array[filas*columnas],0);
  }

  ~Array()
  {
    delete[] array;
  }

  int Filas() const
  { return filas; }

  int Columnas() const
  { return columnas; }

  int* operator[](int fila)
  { return &array[fila*columnas]; }
};

int main () {

  Array array(3,2);
  array[1][1] = 3;
  array[2][0] = 1;

  for(int i=0;i<array.Filas();i++)
  {
    for(int j=0;j<array.Columnas();j++)
      std::cout << array[i][j] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Un saludo.

Comment: Ningún estándar de C++ acepta [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). En C++ se usa `new`, no `malloc`.

Comment: tienes razón, he mezclado conceptos de C y de C++.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42200/discussion-between-paperbirdmaster-and-eferion).